# HTTP-connection with credentials to get HTML document

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, xcode, http

I would like to download an HTML documents(s) to parse the content. The server asks before entering this site to put in my user credentials. In Java I arrived with a basic authentication in an asynchronous task like this (JSoup):

```
String base64login = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(loginDaten.getBytes()));
Document parsableDoc = Jsoup.connect(myUrl).header("Authorization","Basic"+base64login)
   .timeout(3000)
   .get();
```

but in Objective-C it doesn't work so simple as I thought. Here I want to save the website in an NSData-Object or something similar (for example NSString). Got any ideas to solve this as simple as possible? (I'm such a pro in this sector as you can see…)

Comment: What have you tried in objective-c?  (Hint: NSURLConnection is where you'll need to go)

Comment: I read a tutorial about NSMutableURLRequest. 
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

The output was decoded, maybe you could say me, how to apply an encoding to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the NSURLConnection class ad NSMutableURLRequest. The idea is that you let the NSMutableURLRequest know what kind of auth method you want to use, and the credentials (login/password).
The following code should do it. (You will need the NSdata category for base64Encoding in this link http://cocoadev.com/wiki/BaseSixtyFour )

```
self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", @"login",@"password"];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64Encoding]];
[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
   [self.receivedData appendData:data];
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
   if ([self.receivedData length] >0)
      NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:downloadedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSLog(@"The HTML String Is : %@", result);

{
```

Comment: I tried this one, but I don't understand how to get the html in a string or an NSData output...

Comment: I've updated the code. You have to initialize an NSMutableData object where you will store the data as it is being received. To do so the method didReceiveData: will be called regularly, and in there you will append the new data as it is received.

Once it is done receiving it, the delegate method connectionDidFinishLoading: will be called, where you can make a string with the resulting data.

Comment: Before I have seen your update, I had done an NSLog: <3c21444f 43545950 45204854 4d4c2050 55424c49 4320222d 2f2f4945 54462f2f 44544420 48544d4c 20322e30 2f2f454e 223e0a3c 68746d6c 3e3c6865 61643e0a 3c746974 6c653e34 30312041 7574686f 72697a61 74696f6e 20526571 75697265 643c2f74 69746c65 3e0a3c2f 68656164 3e3c626f 64793e0a 3c68313e 41757468 …